# 2.5" or 3" Lift - Do I need to replace control arms (Jeep // For offroading)

Tags: suspension, jeep, suspension-geometry, lifting, gladiator

Hey so I have a 2020 Jeep Gladiator (Sport S). I want to do a 2.5" or 3" lift to help with clearance (approach / breakover angles specifically) but if I do I'm wondering if I should replace the control arms. I hear that under 3" I wouldn't need new control arms but then some places suggest since I'm off-roading (light to medium) that added articulation means it's a good idea.

Also does 2.5 to 3 inch lift change much mechanically?  Seem nominal but that 3" seems to be a pretty strong cutoff line.

Comment: I have not contemplated a lift that high, so take with a grain of salt (and why a comment not an answer): you are changing a lot of geometry and alignment of things with such a lift, so reliability and on-road (not just off-road) performance should be a consideration. Also consider how the vehicle will be loaded while off-road. Looking into a 1.5" lift on my Tacoma, I would be replacing most everything.